# How to bring activity to front using finish from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish, home-button

i have two activities: A and B.

from A to B:

**onCreate**

```
Context context = this;
```

**onClick**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

from B to A:
(if B has a button to return to A)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
      finish();
   }
});
```

But if the flow is like:

A call B, the user that is watching B clicks Home button and click again B from launched activities and clicks the button to call finish(), it goes to Home and not to my first activity A. How can i do it?

EDIT:

**flow**

1. A->B                          // with startActivity(Intent);
2. B->Home                       // clicking home button on device
3. Home->B                       // clicking my app from launched activities
4. B.finish() -> Home and not A  // finish or onBackPressed do the same

Comment: you can use activity single task and use intent to start the activity then only the last instance will be brought to front if an instance exists(and on create wont be executed)

Comment: that is what i've done ;)

Comment: Is your activity A single task?

Comment: yes.. so startActivity will bring that activity to the front instead creating new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this :-

WHY ARE YOUR USING `getApplicationContext()` instead of use `this` or `Activity A name.`

**A ->B**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(yourcurrentActivity,B.class);
 startActivty(i);
```

**B ->A**

call `finish()`

**update** if you are  using this:- remove it

```
android:noHistory="true";
```

Comment: i don't want to start again my A class.. i don't need to execute code inside onCreate

Comment: u want to come at home or FirstActivity after finish()

Comment: FirstActivity.. but i don't need to create again FirstActivity but just bring it to front hiding the Second one

Comment: no way.. (see edit) with myApplication instead getApplicationContext() it goes to home and not in firstActivity

Comment: android:noHistory="false" in your manifest file with in your first activity or remove this....if u r using it.

Comment: i solved simply: Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MyFirstClass.class);
      getActivity().startActivity(i);
    
      getActivity().finish();

Comment: did you use this keyword or your activtity name instead of getApplicationContext..try this once because getActivity not a good idea.

Comment: that is a PreferenceFragment, i need to call getActivity :)

Answer (score 0):

call

```
onBackPressed();
```

instead of

```
finish();
```

Comment: sorry... but onBackPressed() do the same as finish() -> A->B, B->Home,Home->B,(B.onBackPressed() || B.finish()) -> Home and not A

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(B.this,B.class));
```

and finish() in activity A as

```
// in your activity A
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

and

```
public void OnBackPressed()
{
finish();
}
```

Comment: i don't want to start again A class

Comment: sorry, but why i have to execute finish() on activity A?

Comment: you say i don't want to start again A class. so it will finish activity A. otherwise when you press back button it will goto activity A

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

Comment: When posting code as your answer, also explain why and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

check below code: i have 3 activity : MainActivity, A_Acvitiy, B_actiivty (Hope its worked as per your req..)

```
package com.example.androidtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void callActivity(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            // A
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, A_activity.class));
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            // B
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, B_activity.class));
            if (GeneraClass.isFormB) {
                            GeneraClass.isFormB = false;
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A_activity:

```
package com.example.androidtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class A_activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_layout);
    }

    public void callActivity(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            // B
            startActivity(new Intent(A_activity.this, B_activity.class));
                 finish();
        }

    }

}
```

b_activity:

```
package com.example.androidtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class B_activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.b_layout);
    }

    public void callActivity(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.home) {
            // home
            GeneraClass.isFormB = true;
            startActivity(new Intent(B_activity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

my extra class:

```
package com.example.androidtest;

public class GeneraClass {

    public static boolean isFormB = false;
}
```

So, **`Home-->A(finish)-->B--->Home(if from b then finish)-->B-->Back--> Home --->Back--> exit App`**